# IIS 7.5 (Win7 Pro x64) AppPool stopping and features mising

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, iis-7.5

i struggle with IIS 7.5.

------Settings-------------

Firstly i created a setup of IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 professional, created a website, webservices, databases and so on. On the test machine everything went fine, evrything is accesible from localhost or from the web.

Then I created a Virtual Machine in VMWare with a silent installation of Windows 7 Professional. The installation routine installs everything including IIS-features, www-features, .Net 4.0 and so on, with the same settings as in the main machine.

I then migrated the settings from the main machine to the IIS installation via "shared configuration". Went fine, i can see my ApplicationPools, the settings, everything is the same as in the main machine.

--------Problem-------

Now the problem is, i always get error 503. I researched a little bit, and i found out that **EVERYTIME i try to access localhost from a browser, the ApplicationPool which is used for my Webservice stopps**.

So the i wanted to check the logging, but **in the "features" tab**, when selected the website, **only contains the element "configuration editor"**... this too appears when i just install Windows 7 including IIS and the therefore necesary components, without migrating any configurations.

I guess something went wrong during the installation, but i cant figure out what. Basically the settings in the main machine and in the virtual one are the same.

Anyone got some ideas? Thanks in advance!